# bind data to datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem with my `datagridview`. The idea is to create a local stored entry to a `datagridview` *(dgv)*. The problem is that I want to filter the dgv for some specific keywords and my dgv content is, as I mentioned, local stored. There is no DataSet / DataBinding, etc...

Now I wish to create a "collection" to store and filter all of my entries properly.

What is the best way to create a "collection" ?

The dvg should be filtered by a treeview control. If i´m pressing on (e.g: "test" - dvg should filter all of its entries instantly) - No problem because I can read the current selected nodes text.

The real problem is to create a properly working "collection" to filter and save my entries. I´ve already set the column names.

by the way: This is my method to save the dvg an the treeview collection

```
using (Stream file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(file, tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file);
    bw.Write(gridview.ColumnCount);
    bw.Write(gridview.RowCount);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in gridview.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            object val = item.Cells[i].Value;
            if (val == null)
            {
                bw.Write(false);
                bw.Write(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bw.Write(true);
                bw.Write(val.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you guys have some good advices for me ?

Comment: If you avoiding data binding because you think it requires a database, it does not. You do want to databind a `DataTable` or a `List<T>`.

Comment: Yes I want to bind a datatable or a list. The problem I have is to set the columns properly. I can add a list, but I don´t know how to fill it.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Test");
            dt.Rows.Add(name); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;  

This is my last attempt. But I can not see the entries in the datagridview

Comment: Please add updates to the question instead of in comments. You can bind a `DataTable` directly, you don't need to add it to a `DataSet`. What you have not shown is populating the `DataTable`. If you bind an empty table, you of course won't see any data.